# Angular: ng-view not displaying properly

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to show a View using ng-view, but it's not working as it should be.

Trips.cshtml:

```
  @section Scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/simpleControls.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app-trips.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/tripsController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
}

<div class="row" ng-app="app-trips">

<div ng-view></div>
```

App-trips.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app-trips", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                controller: "tripsController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl:" /views/tripsView.html"
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
        });
})();
```

And I am trying to show a view tripsView.html that is in /wwwroot/views.

bower.json:

```
"angular" : "~1.6.5",
"angular-route" : "~1.6.5",
"jquery": "2.2.0",
"bootstrap" : "3.3.7"
```

tripsView.html:

```
<p>hello world </p>
```

I get an error using a diferent non connected script:

```
$(function (){
########## not connected stuff
})();
```

error: *"is not a function"*, could this be connected? Even thought the script is working fine.

Comment: do you see any console errors

Comment: @Sajeetharan None, asp.net is also not showing any errors.

Comment: I think it know where could be the problem. I think asp.net is not working properly on this page. @ViewBag.Tittle is also not shown any more, even though that it was before